# R : select groups with only missing values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a data frame which looks like this :

```
group = c(rep("a",3), rep("b",5), rep("c",4), rep("d",4))
value = c(NA, NA, NA, 5,7,8,NA,9, NA,NA,NA,NA, 7,9,7,2)
data = cbind(group, value)
data = as.data.frame(data)
```

[image]

And I want to display a new table with groups that contain only NA. Namely groups A and C, but not group B because there are some values. How can I do that?

the result I want should look like this table :

[image]

thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: How exactly will the new table look like? You should also provide the output table with a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Base R` we can use `aggregate()`

**Code**

```
# check which group only consists of NAs
tmp1 <- aggregate(data$value, list(data$group), function(x){
  all(is.na(x))
})

# subset to desired data format
tmp1[tmp1$x == T,]

#   Group.1    x
# 1       a TRUE
# 3       c TRUE
```

**Update**

We can even make this a little more legible and also keep variable names using
`na.pass`

```
# check which group only consists of NAs
tmp1 <- aggregate(value ~ group, data, function(x){
  all(is.na(x))
}, na.action = na.pass)

# subset 
tmp1[tmp1$value == T,]

#   group value
# 1     a  TRUE
# 3     c  TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a kind of hack way to do it if you're only interested in keeping a dataframe where *all* values for a respective group are `NA`:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = 'updown') %>% 
  filter(is.na(value))
```

Gives us:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Groups:   group [2]
  group value
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     NA   
2 a     NA   
3 a     NA   
4 c     NA   
5 c     NA   
6 c     NA   
7 c     NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the tidyverse, finding out which group consists of only NA is fairly straightforward:

```
library(tidyverse)
result <- data %>%
group_by(group) %>%
summarize(onlyNA = all(is.na(value)))
```

you can then filter the result: `filter(result, onlyNA == T)`

the tidyverse is quite a large dependency, so installing and loading it for this small script might be overkill depending on the overall size of your project. In that case, see the answer by Base_R_Best_R. I think this code here is more legible, though.

Comment: Nice solution! `tidyverse` is the umbrella package. The same result can be achieved by importing just the `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, sum(is.na(value)) == .N, group]
```